# I,m trying to upload image using google drive api but i have got some error in response

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I,m trying to upload image using google drive api but i have got some error in response as bellow.

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()"

Comment: I think that to provide your script for replicating your issue is provided, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.   If you are referencing any tutorials, samples or documentation links to them can also help others help you.

Comment: What is the full message of the `403`?

Answer (score 1):

@AsishMishra The status code 403 is for.

The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).

If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access. The client SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same credentials. The client MAY repeat the request with new or different credentials. However, a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials.

Check if you are adding the credentials or something is missing on your api.